# Stackoverflow When Removing Items from Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

So I have a binary tree with data and I have currently written a remove method for the binary tree that should remove a node while still maintaining the binary tree as a balanced tree.

Currently I am doing the remove like this:

```
public Node remove(K key) {

    return removeHelper(key, root, null);

}

public Node removeHelper(K key, Node targetNode, Node parent) {

    if (targetNode == null) {

        return targetNode;

    } else {

        if (key.compareTo(targetNode.key) == 0) {

            // we have found the item we are looking for!
            // CASE #1 - The target node does not have any children
            if (targetNode.left == null && targetNode.right == null) {

                if (parent != null) {
                    if (parent.left.equals(targetNode)) {
                        parent.left = null;
                    } else if (parent.right.equals(targetNode)) {
                        parent.right = null;
                    }
                }

                // CASE #2. target node only has a one child, right or left.
            } else if (targetNode.left == null) {

                targetNode = targetNode.right;

            } else if (targetNode.right == null) {

                targetNode = targetNode.left;

                // CASE #3 - It has 2 children.
            } else {

                Node temp = targetNode;
                Node rightMin = FindMin(temp.right);
                targetNode.key = rightMin.key;
                targetNode.value = rightMin.value;

            }

        } else if (key.compareTo(targetNode.key) < 0) {
            return removeHelper(key, targetNode.left, targetNode);
        } else if (key.compareTo(targetNode.key) > 0) {
            return removeHelper(key, targetNode.right, targetNode);
        } else {
            return targetNode;
        }

    }

    return targetNode;
}
```

and here is the FindMin method:

```
//Finding the minimum node in this subtree passed in
private Node FindMin(Node rootNode) {

    if (rootNode.left == null) {
        return rootNode;
    } else {
        return FindMin(rootNode.left);
    }

}
```

And then I am trying to test the removal of nodes like such:

```
BinarySearchTree<Integer, String> tree = new BinarySearchTree<Integer, String>();
    tree.put(40, "Forty");
    tree.put(20, "Twenty");
    tree.put(60, "Sixty");
    tree.put(10, "Ten");
    tree.put(30, "Thirty");
    tree.put(50, "Fifty");
    tree.put(70, "Seventy");
    tree.put(4, "four");

    tree.remove(70);
    tree.remove(60);
    System.out.println(tree);
```

And the output from this is:
(4:four)(10:Ten)(20:Twenty)(30:Thirty)(40:Forty)(50:Fifty)(60:Sixty)

As you can see, the 70 is being remove successfully but the 60 is not being removed for some reason. I tried changing around my code a bit but I usually run into a stackoverflow error when doing so.

Anyone see an issue or case I am missing here?

Comment: stackoverflow error normally occurs when you use recursive methods. It is your case. You should check `removeHelper` recursion.

Comment: Side note: add something along the lines of `else { throw new Exception(...); }` (an assertion would work well here, too) to the `if (parent.left.equals(targetNode)) { parent.left = null; } else if (parent.right.equals(targetNode)) { parent.right = null; }`. This will make bugs in your code fail fast instead of creating hard to diagnose behavior.

Comment: The lines `targetNode = targetNode.right;` and it's sibling with `.left` look suspicious. These just discard the current node from the *method's* scope; they don't update the tree at all. Shouldn't those blocks *assign* the child node to one of the parent's nodes?